# Is there a better way to combine two queries other than using UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two queries that are identical. I have a case where I want to fetch all orders related to a collection. I could think of using UNION but it is too slow.

query 1:
Here I am trying to query orders that have type 2 which means the ref_id is referencing a variant.

orders -> order_items -> varaints -> products -> lines -> collections

```
SELECT
    `orders`.*
FROM
    `orders`
    LEFT JOIN `order_items` ON `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id`
    LEFT JOIN `variants` ON `order_items`.`ref_id` = `variants`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `line_products` ON `variants`.`parent_id` = `line_products`.`product_id`
        AND `order_items`.`type` = 2
    LEFT JOIN `collection_line` ON `line_products`.`line_id` = `collection_line`.`line_id`
WHERE
    `collection_line`.`collection_id` = 55;
```

query 2:
Here I am trying to query orders that have item type 1 which means the ref_id is referencing a product.

orders -> order_items -> products -> lines -> collections

```
 SELECT
        `orders`.*
    FROM
        `orders`
        LEFT JOIN `order_items` ON `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id`
        LEFT JOIN `line_products` ON `order_items`.`ref_id` = `line_products`.`product_id`
            AND `order_items`.`type` = 1
        LEFT JOIN `collection_line` ON `line_products`.`line_id` = `collection_line`.`line_id`
    WHERE
        `collection_line`.`collection_id` = 55;
```

Is there a way I can combine and optimize these two queries?

Comment: `order_items`.`type` IN (2,1)

Comment: Having one column serve for two foreign keys is poor design: Use separate columns.

Comment: @golimar the join tables are different based on type.

Comment: Your final join is an inner join

Comment: Do the two queries ever return the same product data?

Comment: 1) How slow is slow? 2) Can you update your question with all table definition by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`. 3) How many (estimated) rows of data each table has? 4) It's already being mentioned but `LEFT JOIN collection_line ..` is already being turned to `INNER JOIN` when you do `WHERE collection_line.collection_id=55;`

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by product data?

Comment: sorry, will try to update the question following https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example guidelines.

Comment: @Laze Do the two queries ever return some duplicate data from what you referred to in your question as *products -> lines -> collections* ?

Comment: "combine" & "optimize" don't mean anything in particular. [mre] PS Learn about subqueries. PS LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collection_line` sounds like a many-to-many mapping table.  If so, follow the indexing advice here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table  In particular, a composite index on `(collection_id, line_id)` is needed.
Similarly for `line_products`.

`p` needs `(line_id, product_id)`
`i`: `(ref_id, type, order_id)`

`LEFT` is probably unnecessary; see if you get the same results without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT
    `orders`.*
FROM
    `orders`
    LEFT JOIN `order_items` ON `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id`
    LEFT JOIN `variants` ON `order_items`.`ref_id` = `variants`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `line_products` ON `variants`.`parent_id` = `line_products`.`product_id`
        AND `order_items`.`type` IN ('1', '2')
    LEFT JOIN `collection_line` ON `line_products`.`line_id` = `collection_line`.`line_id`
WHERE
    `collection_line`.`collection_id` = 55;
```

Use `IN`

Comment: using this query would only query variants tables while the result expected is to query products table if order_items.type is 1.

Answer (score 0):

This works a single order through and has double left-joins going on.  One for the variant, the second on the default line products / collection.  You had each instance of a WHERE clause to include "collection_id = 55" which changes a left-join to an INNER join for requirement purposes.

So, with the one root-level orders table both left-joins can be simultaneous.  The only thing to add is the "WHERE" clause.  So, whichever is the condition of NOT null, it should be one or the other.

```
select
      o.*
   from
      ( SELECT DISTINCT 
              oi.order_id
           FROM
              order_items oi
                 LEFT JOIN variants v
                    ON oi.ref_id = v.id
                    AND oi.type = 2
                    LEFT JOIN line_products lp
                        ON v.parent_id = lp.product_id
                        LEFT JOIN collection_line cl 
                            ON lp.line_id = cl.line_id
                            AND cl.collection_id = 55;
    
                 LEFT JOIN line_products lp2
                    ON oi2.ref_id = lp2.product_id
                    AND oi2.type = 1
                    LEFT JOIN collection_line cl2
                        ON lp2.line_id = cl2.line_id
                        AND cl2.collection_id = 55
           where
                  oi.type in ( 1,  2 )
              AND (    cl.collection_id = 55
                   OR  cl2.collection_id = 55 )) PQ
      JOIN Orders o
         on PQ.order_id = o.id
```

By having the OR, it does not REQUIRE on both sides, but as long as ONE of them is qualified the order should return.  Since it MAY be possible for the joins to create multiple returns for the same order, and you are not pulling status.  Then join those unique IDs back to orders table